# OpenGL ES 2 doesn't work on Android API23

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es

In my app I'm doing some image pixels manipulations.
My code based on [THIS](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest.java.txt) example.

The only change that I've made is to change the `FRAGMENT_SHADER` to a grayscale and it looks like this:

```
private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
        "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
        "precision mediump float;\n" +      // highp here doesn't seem to matter
        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
        "    vec4 tc = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
        "    gl_FragColor.r = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
        "    gl_FragColor.g = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
        "    gl_FragColor.b = tc.r * 0.3 + tc.g * 0.59 + tc.b * 0.11;\n" +
        "}\n";
```

The problem:
I've recorded a video from Galaxy s7 device, after recording I've taken the recorded video and I was reading the first frame from 2 different devices(Galaxy S7 and Galaxy s3), I found that the pixel values are absolutely different between those devices.

Does someone know why does it happen? and what can I do in order to solve this issue, since my algorithm fails because of this differences?

**Update:**

This is example of the diferences I've got.

**Gaaxy S3:**
Part of the matrix
213, 214, 212, 214, 216, 214, 213, 212, 212, 212, 213, 214, 214, 214, 213, 213, 214, 214, 214, 214, 212, 213, 212, 213, 212, 214, 214, 212, 212, 210, 211, 210, 211, 210, 211, 211, 214, 211, 214, 213, 213, 214, 214, 216, 216, 216, 215, 215, 216, 212, 213, 213, 214, 213, 213, 212, 211, 209, 209, 207, 208, 208, 210, 211, 209, 207, 209, 210, 217, 219, 216, 209, 209, 210, 210, 210, 211, 209, 207, 205, 205, 206, 210, 210, 220, 211, 202, 210, 211, 206, 206, 209, 210, 211, 213, 219, 222, 216, 217, 217

count of non zeroes pixels: 1632816

Sum of all the pixels: 3.1834445E8

**Galaxy S7:**
same part of the Matrix as Galaxy 3
164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164, 164

count of non-zeros pixels: 1063680

Sum of all the pixels: 1.6593408E8

**Update2:**

I found that the image received is absolutely ruined, but the video recorded well.
This is the good image from Galaxy S3:
[image]

And this is the image I've got from Galaxy S7 (Same frame#)
[image]

I have no Idea at all what is going here, but I know that the last image is the same for all Marshmallow devices(Galaxy S6,S7 and Huawei)

Comment: could you please elaborate on the difference between the pixel values between the 2 devices? Adding a screenshot showing the differences would help also.

Comment: I will update it, Thanks

Comment: Also, give us more info on how are you recording the video?

Comment: I'm using MediaRecorder in order to record the video

Comment: Possible to share more of your program? To get that kind of horizontal banding it smells more like an input data problem, not a shader problem.

Comment: The code I'm using is really close to the code in the example I've linked since I based on this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a week of hard work to find the solution, it was found!

As I said I based on bigflake example and in this example there is an option to invert the frame and in the example that what was done.

By changing the invert to false the problem was fixed.

I'll really appreciate if someone can explain me the reason that there is invert to the frame, and why it was decided to set it as "true" by default.

Thannks for all your help!

This is the change that I've made if it wasn't clear enough:

```
outputSurface.drawImage(false);
```